# In DelugeRPG, how do you get Groudon?

Tags: deluge-rpg

Anybody here know how to get a Groudon in DelugeRPG? I looked in every area, but I could not find it!

I need this bad!

Comment: You could get one from trading, or there's probably a rare chance of finding it

Comment: next time, can u put it as a comment. just asking

Comment: Do you mean answer? I've done so

Comment: @hadiro, yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legendaries are probably the hardest pokemon to find.  I'd think that the volcano area would have Groudon, as that is where he is located in Pokemon Emerald/Ruby.

You could try trading with someone to get it as well

Answer (score 1):

Find Groudon at map 19 it has a 33% chance you can find it. I found one in the same map , map 19 and now it is primal groudon

Comment: Where on map 19?

Answer (score -3):

You can get it after you have kyogre

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: ummmmmmm.. ummmmmmmmmm..... how???????